# Autocomplete for CSS attribute names in Linux Chrome Developer console

Tags: linux, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using Linux Chrome Stable under Ubuntu 14.04. All works perfect but when I go to the web developer tools, and start typing a new rule for example "flo" for "float" it shows a context menu but when I press tab button, it does not auto complete it. This didn't happen on the windows version, is this an option I have to change or anything on the linux chrome?

Comment: Hi Guys! I'm back, its now working. Chrome got updated recently.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a bug filed for Chrome 35 Linux that describes this issue:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=376763

My guess is that it's related somehow to Aura being integrated for Linux in Chrome 35. You can try starring the issue to lend more urgency to fixing it.

According to comment 26 (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=376763#c26), the issue no longer exists in Chrome 36 beta, so if you absolutely have to have autocomplete working right away, then you can use that version.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works in Chrome Linux. You can use the mouse to select from the suggestions or, if you want to do it with keyboard only, you can use `end` to go to the end of the current item in the list and then press tab. I don't think you can change this behaviour.

Comment: I tried the end thing but no luck.. Oh well.. this was very useful

Comment: The "end thing" works for me.. E.g. I click after `{` to add new rule,  type 'fl', now 'float' is the selected suggestion, press `End` button, cursor jumps to end of word 'float', now press `Tab`, cursor jumps to value field and 'float' is now set as name and is red. I use Version 35.0.1916.114 on Debian.